# Настройка маршрутизатора Cisco 891-F

Tags: сеть, настройка, lan, router, cisco

Доброго времени суток. 
Имеется маршрутизатор Cisco 891-f. Необходимо с его помощью организовать локальную сеть таким образом:

- Интерфейсы Gigabit Ethernet 0, 4, 5 Смотрят в одну подсеть с адресом 192.168.50.1/24
- Интерфейс Gigabit Ethernet 1 - в подсеть с адресом 192.168.55.1/24
- Интерфейс Gigabit Ethernet 2 - в подсеть с адресом 192.168.60.1/24
- Интерфейс Gigabit Ethernet 8 - к провайдеру

Так как интерфейсы GigabitEthernet 0-7 представлены как интерфейсы второго уровня, для поддержки IP протокола были созданы Vlan интерфейсы, на которые приземляются соответствующие интерфейсы роутера. Протестировать работоспособность сети в данный момент не представляется возможным, поэтому я хотел узнать, что необходимо добавить в конфигурационный файл, чтобы данная сеть могла работать.

```
Current configuration : 3378 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 14:26:39 UTC Fri Apr 22 2016 by admin
!
version 15.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname kaf
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no logging console
enable secret 5 $1$gCIa$BcurCO2Mk2PJUkYC6apSl.
enable password 7 08701E1D5D4C
!
aaa new-model
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
no process cpu extended history
no process cpu autoprofile hog
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.60.1

ip dhcp pool RE1_TEST_POOL
host 192.168.69.69 255.255.255.0
client-identifier 0100.0e2e.6af9.39
client-name RE1_TEST
!
!
!
ip domain name dozen.mephi.ru
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
no cdp run
!
ip ssh time-out 30
ip ssh authentication-retries 2
ip ssh source-interface GigabitEthernet8
ip ssh version 2
!
interface BRI0
 no ip address
 encapsulation hdlc
 shutdown
 isdn termination multidrop
 no cdp enable
!
interface FastEthernet0
 description Private router subnet interface
 ip address 192.168.69.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0
 switchport access vlan 10
 no ip address
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 switchport access vlan 20
 no ip address
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet2
 switchport access vlan 30
 no ip address
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet3
 switchport access vlan 40
 no ip address
 shutdown
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet4
 switchport access vlan 20
 no ip address
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet5
switchport access vlan 20     
no ip address
no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet8
 ip address 192.168.50.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no cdp enable
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan10
 description Kaf subnet interface
 ip address 192.168.51.1 255.255.255.0
 ip accounting output-packets
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface Vlan20
 description Unix server subnet interface
 ip address 192.168.55.1 255.255.255.0
 ip accounting output-packets
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface Vlan30
 description Web server subnet interface
 ip address 192.168.60.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface Async3
 no ip address
 encapsulation slip
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
ip access-list standard ACL_REMOTE_ACCESS
 permit 192.168.69.2
!
no service-routing capabilities-manager
!
snmp-server community public RO
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
mgcp behavior rsip-range tgcp-only
mgcp behavior comedia-role none
mgcp behavior comedia-check-media-src disable
mgcp behavior comedia-sdp-force disable
!
mgcp profile default
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 no modem enable
 line aux 0
line 3
 modem InOut
 speed 115200
 flowcontrol hardware
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 password 7 12485744465E
 logging synchronous
 transport input ssh
 transport output ssh
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
!
!
!
end
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По всей видимости, не настроен NAT. Необходимо добавить:

```
ip access-list extended 140
permit ip 192.168.50.0 255.255.255.0 any
permit ip 192.168.55.0 255.255.255.0 any
permit ip 192.168.60.0 255.255.255.0 any
ip nat inside source list 140 interface (WAN-интерфейс) overload
```

Далее надо посмотреть, какой у тебя тип WAN и правильно его настроить (сейчас на Gi8 серый IP висит). После чего повесить на него NAT:
    interface (WAN-интерфейс) ip nat outside

и шлюз:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 (WAN-интерфейс) (опционально: IP провайдерского устройства)
```

Answer (score 0):

на беглыф взгляд вроде норм.
interface GigabitEthernet8
nat outside добавить надо есали это провайдер
+ нет маршрута на шлюз провайдера.